# Monitor Requires Power Cycle after Restart or Power Up

Tags: windows-7, display

I have a display that does not receive a signal unless it is powered off, then on while the Windows 7 system connected to it is online.

The monitor reports that it is in Standby during this exercise. The power indicator on the monitor is flashing, (standby).

Here are two scenarios:
1) Screen is on, PC is on. Restart PC. Screen is receiving no signal. Turn screen off, turn screen on, now I have a signal.

2) Screen and PC are both off. Both powered on at the same time. The screen receives no signal. Once windows is loaded, turn screen off, turn screen on, signal.

This happens every time. It is not elusive.

The screen has DVI and Analog inputs. Regardless of which cable is used I get the exact same issue.

Switching display sources does not fix the problem. The monitor will cycle through all available sources with no results till I cycle power to the monitor. There are no settings on the monitor that indicate a sleep mode is possible.

I do not have this problem with other monitors, which leads me to believe that it is a monitor setting. However, I do not have this problem with this monitor when connected to other windows 7 systems. I've only seen this problem when the two are together.

I realize there are similar questions, but as far as I've been able to find, this one is unique.

Is there any setting I am not aware of that lets a monitor know it is being used or not? I can not see any settings to indicate this is the case.

This would not normally be a problem except that this is a panel mount monitor, and the power button is on the back of the display.

EDIT:
I have reinstalled the drivers, this does nothing. I would like to point out that I have no display even during boot. So while the system is posting, or if I hit delete after a restart and I should be viewing the BIOS, I am viewing nothing. I don't believe drivers come into play at that point.

I have also recently disabled sleep functions in the BIOS, thinking that may be the issue.

Comment: Preliminary questions: What model is your PC? What is the make of your video adapter card? Do you have both video card and on-board graphics? Have you fully patched Windows including optional Windows Updates (except Bing Desktop)?

Comment: It only has on-board graphics. It is an embedded chipset graphics card.

Comment: I'm trying to work with the equipment manufacturer right now to figure out if I can upgrade the driver, unfortunately it's a graphics adapter driver built with Intel IEGD.

Comment: Intel drivers are found in the [Intel Download Center](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/).

Comment: Does cycling through the output modes with windows-P have any effect?

Comment: @vinnief No, that doesn't help, thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

My father in law had almost the same problem and it turned out to be a faulty monitor. His monitor would *occasionally* wake up if we re-seated the DVI cable. The fact that the same thing happened when I switched him over to display port/VGA with persisting symptoms led me to believe it was either a problem with his graphics card or monitor (likely monitor).

Are you able to test your monitor on another known good PC/laptop? This could help you rule out a faulty monitor. If you have access to another known-good monitor, you could test your PC as well to rule out faulty graphics card/motherboard.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a faulty monitor, as other monitors do not experience this issue. The monitor also works with other PCs. Just not together.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps to help troubleshoot this kind of issues:

1. Test your monitor with another computer. If the monitor works as expected it's then a problem with your **video output**. Try installing the latest drivers on your computer or even update your BIOS (if applicable). If that doesn't work, your video output may be physically damaged.
2. If you don't have another computer at hand, test your computer with another monitor.
3. If the problem persists, it's most likely an issue with the **input controller** of your monitor. It checks for a signal, and if it doesn't receive one it'd stay there until it's powered on again. This may be due to a faulty transistor that prevents the controller to *try to receive* a signal again. Since monitors are devices that work with high tensions but require sensible components, they're pretty much prone to this kind of issues, specially because of manufacturing issues, like bad soldering.

Comment: 1 and 2, I've tested both these components with other monitors/PCs. The issue is that this is a panel PC and a panel monitor, which is why I need them to work together. As for 3, if it works with other PCs, does that rule this out?

Comment: Of course, if 1 and 2 work it's for sure not 3. It may be your video output, not the input.